# Missing php_ssh2.dll extension for php 7.2 (windows)

Tags: php, php-extension

Today I wanted to update my dev machine with new php so i downloaded and set up PHP 7.2.7 x64.

After that I sterted collecting missing modules and everything goes fine till i came to the last one: php_ssh2.dll.
Downloaded latest version 1.1.2 from https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Error:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: ssh2: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20160303
PHP    compiled with module API=20170718
These options need to match
```

Anyone have any tips for me how to make it work?

Comment: What version did you download? 7.1 TS x64 ? Are you on Apache or IIS?

Comment: As I wrote in my question PHP 7.2.7 x64 NTS for Windows so IIS.

Comment: Nowhere NTS or IIS is specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, PHP 7.2.x is built using VC15 and the latest SSH2 module is [v1.1.2 which was built on VC14](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/1.1.2/).

So you need to either downgrade to PHP 7.1.x or wait for the PHP team to compile SSH2 in VC15.

Additionally, I have no experience with this but you could decide to compile it yourself in VC15 if you are comfortable with that sort of thing.

---

**Update:**

SSH 1.1.2 now has a VC15 build at https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/1.1.2/

The latest SSH is 1.2 which currently has PHP 7.1-7.4 builds: https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/1.2/

Answer (score 5):

I have compiled SSH2 module for PHP 7.2 (and PHP 7.3) on Windows. It is available at https://github.com/nufue/pecl-ssh2-windows